# Magento2 upgrade Getting error

Tags: magento2

after upgarde getting this error  Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails `(au.#sql-40d4_c, CONSTRAINT SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_`

Answer (score 0):

It just simply means that the value for column *COLUMN_NAME* on table TABLE_NAME1 you are inserting doesn't exist on table TABLE_NAME2

The value "abcdefgh" you are inserting for column *COLUMN_NAME* does not exist on table youa re trying to inssert.

check your database table

Comment: but i am upgrading my magento   <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" table="sales_order"
                    column="customer_id" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id"
                    onDelete="SET NULL"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from sales_order where customer_id not in (select `entity_id` from `customer_entity`)
```